# calling exe through php

Tags: php, iis, mapi

I have an exe file that I'm calling through php using the  'system' command. The exe file then makes calls to Microsoft mapi for some reason that i don't know the mapi is not getting initialized when i call the exe through php but if i run the exe from command line it works fine. Any clue why?

p.s I m running iis on 2008 server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This likely has to do with permissions.  PHP will run under whatever user account IIS is configured for that resource.

Also, make sure your paths are correct.  If you haven't already, start by explicitly defining the path.

Comment: Besides permissions, it could also be environment variables and the current working directory when executed.

Comment: @wallyk, Good point.  I had assumed user16458 checked that... but that is probably a bad assumption to make.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I have defined all the paths explicitly and gave the user account iis full control but still the mapi fails to initialize and its getting beyond frustrating now. when i run the php file the executable does get called but the mapi fails to initialize any clue why? :(